# Can't connect to the server ftp.ch.debian.org

Tags: linux, debian, apt

I want to update `apt-get update`, but I got an error.
When I try to install something I get the same error.

This is my network configuration:

[image: network]

[image: Output of cat /etc/resolv.conf]

[image: Error in Debian]

Comment: Can you post the output of `cat /etc/resolv.conf` ?

Comment: In general avoid including screenshots of text. Just include the text. Also, you can temporarily set the locals so the error message output is in English. e.g. `LANG=en_US.UTF-8 apt-get update` will probably work (untested).

Answer (score 0):

- The nameserver configured in your `/etc/resolv.conf` is not in the same subnet as the server itself. If your gateway has no route to that subnet the nameserver is not reachable.
- Your interface configuration is not valid. Maybe your IP address should be 192.168.**0**.110 not 192.168.1.110. The IP address, the network address, the broadcast address und the gateway address must all be in the same subnet.

After correcting the problem above, try to ping the nameserver:

```
ping 192.168.243.2
```

Comment: I've changed the IP to 192.168.0.110 and then I've done the ping to 192.168.243.2 but it doesn't work. Message:                From 192.168.0.110 icm_seq=57 Destination Host Unreacheable

Comment: You have to restart the network after changing something in `/etc/network/interfaces`. And the fact that you cannot ping the nameserver is the reason of the problem. Maybe you have to be in that subnet. I don't know your environment. Maybe your ip must be `192.168.243.110`. I can only say: you have to be in the same subnet to reach a machine, or your gateway must route you to it.

Comment: Now I can Ping the 192.168.243.2 but I still can't install or update

Comment: Same error? If yes your nameserver does not resolve the names. Is it a nameserver? Is it internal? Can that nameserver resolve external domain names? You could use 8.8.8.8 (googles nameserver) instead of 192.168.243.2